# Story ID: Corporate brands as massive invisible creatures attaching to human minds with creepy tendrils?

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

I saw this movie once, probably around 2013. I doubt it was made before 2005ish, given the level of CGI. Likely in English — maybe a UK production? — but my second guess is Russian with subtitles.

**What:** The big thing I remember is how the main character somehow acquired the ability to see the hidden truth of society, and he discovers that there are these giant, weird, undulating? organisms floating in the sky which represent different brands (Coca-Cola, Nike, etc.) and connect themselves [physically, with intangible tentacle things] to their human fans/users to feed on them or something. These [CGI] monstrosities are normally invisible, but some people can apparently see the heavy-handed metaphor as real: corporations foster memetic brand-loyalty in order to better parasitize their customers. (Kind of *They Live*-esque now I think about it...) Maybe there was also something about the things feeding on outrage, but I might be stretching my recollection too far there.

I believe the trailer for this film made out the above to be more important to the story than it actually was, and I ended up disappointed.

Other details... Set in contemporary/near-future modern times. My mental image of the city setting seems like London, but IDK. I think the protagonist is male. Surely they put an image of one of these weird CGI brand-creatures on the movie poster!? I would call this an indie film, or at least aiming for a relatively niche audience.

I've been unable to track the thing down based on the intriguing concept alone — hopefully it sparks some memory in you!

Comment: You might be interested in an Asimov's short story in which an alien comes on earth to meet a scientist (I think) and they discuss... well, something related to what the title of your question is talking about (I do not want to spoil you).

Comment: I think you mean ["Hostess"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostess_(short_story)) — thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like you're thinking of ***[Branded](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1368440/)*** (2012).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branded_(2012_film)):

> *Branded* (also known as *The Mad Cow* and *Moscow 2017* (*Москва 2017* in Russian)) is a 2012 Russian–American dark fantasy science fiction film written, produced and directed by Jamie Bradshaw and Aleksandr Dulerayn. It was released on September 7, 2012.

From IMDB:

> In future Moscow, where corporate brands have created a disillusioned population, one man's effort to unlock the truth behind the conspiracy will lead to an epic battle with hidden forces that control the world.

From a [review](https://ishouldbeafilmcritic.com/2012/09/09/review-branded/):

> **the premise of this film is that a corporate conspiracy is actively participating in some kind of scheme involving living, conscious, largely invisible  life-sucking creatures that live in the brands of the biggest, most successful corporations.**

You can see the creatures in the trailer below at around the 1:10 mark.

Comment: That's definitely it, thank you! I'm a little surprised I at all remembered that there was any Russian connection.